# Mixed Classes/Objects and Functions: Code Smell?

Tags: function, powershell, class

I'm looking at refactoring to move to OOP, since I have mandated PS5 for all users, and there are some things in my code that could really benefit from inheritance. My script has lots of utility functions that are used in various places. Some of them will make sense to make helper methods within my classes, but some will be used beyond just one class. So, is it appropriate to keep them as Functions, or is that really a code small it everything should be converted to Classes and Objects? And if a utility function is converted to OOP, what is the mechanism for sharing it between other classes? Do you use a global variable, do you create a local variable and past some how to the object that needs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have spent a great deal of time writing PowerShell classes simply for the sake of exploring the what/how/why during my day-to-day work, and in doing I have started to ask myself the following questions:

1. Am I going to be creating multiple instances of this thing?
2. Do I need it to always have these specific properties & methods?
3. Will this make my scripts harder for me to understand later?

For question one, it will help prevent creating additional complexity on a class you're going to create only a single instance of, when it could just as easily be a series of functions & variables contained in its' own .ps1 script

For question two, you filter out unnecessary complexity even further by eliminating classes that simply don't need to be that rigidly defined. If you have two functions for a single array of strings that contains structured data inside, your time would be better spent ensuring the functions themselves are concise and well documented instead of trying to turn it into a class definition.

Lastly for question three, if you are working on scripts that either presently, or may in the future, be passed on to another individual you need to ask whether this quality of life adjustment will make the intent of your scripts more difficult to understand. This is usually not a problem, but if you're solving an inherently procedural / functional problem with OOP concepts you're simply going to obfuscate the actual solution.

Finally, to address your concern regarding sharing information between classes, simply make your class properties public if they need to be shared between instances or functions and reference those values in the scope the instance is created.

For example, say I have Class Foo with property Bar that I want to access from a script function:

```
Class Foo {
    [Int] $Bar = 0
    Foo () { $Bar = 5 }
}

$MyVar = [Foo]::New()

Function GetBar() {
    return $Script:MyVar.Bar
}

Write-Host GetBar
```

Comment: My script has a series of "tasks" with some common properties and validation, as well as the stuff that is unique, so Classes and Inheritance would really improve things. I also use the tasks in two different contexts, User and Machine, so I have two PS1's, one for each context, and I also have separate Module files for tasks vs helper functions. So, with the functions script scope is limited to what's in an individual module, so Tasks don't have access to Utility functions without jumping through some hoops. But my understanding is that Classes and Functions are different.

Comment: I have found some resources on those issues, so I am really focused on, is mixing Classes/Objects and Functions appropriate, or should I refactor to make EVERYTHING a Class? It seems you are saying a fixed approach is fine?

Comment: Mixing functions & classes is fine from a design perspective.  
  
From what you're describing though, I would personally implement this by defining my classes, functions, etc. in their own files then have a main file that pulls in those definitions and is dedicated to purely the execution of tasks.  That way, you can ensure that everything exists within the scope of a single script and are not trying to juggle several different scopes.

Comment: Interesting. I had found this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1DpPU_xxBc, and he makes it sound like all the classes need to be in the same module file. If I could have a separate file for each class, or maybe for related classes, that would be ideal. My current approach is a small number of PSM1s, with related functions, which are used in different combinations by different "main" PS1 scripts. I am curious what changed between that video and now? Do I need to mandate PS 5.1 perhaps?

Comment: I can't look at the video at the moment, however I can say where your class is available for use is entirely dependent on where the code is 'executed'.

If you have your class definition in 'class.ps1' and you want to use it in a function in 'file.ps1' you need to dot source the file containing the class definition (> . \path\class.p1) inside of file.ps1

If you want to call that function in another script, the code will execute in the scope of the calling script, so you will need to again dot source class.ps1 in the caller to make it available.

Comment: It seems that using module works fine, as long as both classes are in the the same file. I think the guy in the video wanted a separate file for every class. You can seemingly have classes in multiple files, but Inheritance requires a shared file those related classes. I think he says there is an issue with dot sourcing as well. I need to rewatch and see what more I learn on a second viewing.

Comment: Dot sourcing for classes doesn't work. What you'll need to end up doing is either spend a not-insubstantial amount of time reviewing the documentation surrounding creating a script module that has nested modules to dynamically load all the required dependencies OR (my personally preferred solution) add several `using` statements at the top of your shared/primary script to point at the path(s) to the class script definition(s)

e.g.

`using module $PSScriptRoot\Bin\MyClassDefinition.psm1`

Comment: Yeah, Using keyword is looking like the best approach by far. I have some working test code now. How I integrate with Functions will be determined a bit later.